# Javascript: Factorial function works, but I am wondering about the necessity of its internal statements

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that takes a number and returns the factorial of it. It works, but why do you have to "-1" on the first parameter of the second for() statement?

```
var firstFactorial = function(num){
  var numBreakdown = [];
  var total = 1;
  for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    numBreakdown.push(i);
  } 
  for(var y = numBreakdown.length-1; y > 0; y--){
        total *= numBreakdown[y]
    }
  console.log(total);
  return total;
}
firstFactorial(7);
```

Comment: It's subtracting 1 from the length and iterating over the array backwards.

Comment: Array indexes go from 0 to one less than the length. `['first', 'second', 'third']` has indexes 0, 1, and 2. Not sure why you would store the numbers to multiply in an array, though; you can just multiply `total` in the first place.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks for this, but if we are subtracting 1 from the length, in this case it seems like it would start multiplying from 6 and not 7. I don't understand fully.

Comment: @ColinSygiel If we had array [1, 2, 3], the length would be 3, but the highest index would be 2, as Ryan explained. Thus, you start from 3 - 1, which is 2 and go backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, in the array, index (position) of the last element is always one less than the length. And you have to start you operation from the last element which is on length-1 index.

This is your array with all the seven elements and their index..

```
                    numBreakdown=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                                  | | | | | | |
                            index:0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

You can see to access the element 7 you have to use numBreakdown[6] or numBreakdown[length-1], here length=7 or numBreakdown[y] where y=length-1.

Comment: Beautiful, your visualization made it so clear! Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) explained the reasoning behind the `-1` well in the comments above:

> Array indexes go from 0 to one less than the length. ['first', 'second', 'third'] has indexes 0, 1, and 2. Not sure why you would store the numbers to multiply in an array, though; you can just multiply total in the first place.

As for the factorial function, most of it is unnecessary, including the use of arrays to store the factors of the factorial. See the alternative implementation below.

```js
function factorial (n) {
  if (n < 0) throw new TypeError('`n` must be non-negative')
  
  var result = 1
  while (n > 1) result *= n--
  return result
}


console.log(factorial(0)) //=> 1
console.log(factorial(1)) //=> 1
console.log(factorial(7)) //=> 5040
```

If you would like any further clarification or have questions about the above code, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for your simplified code. The concept of an if statement with no {} is new to me but I think this is minor :)

Comment: [Rajeev_ranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3313183/rajeev-ranjan) explains it well in his answer above. The idea is that the numbers you stored at given array index were always exactly (index + 1), and the -1 is to compensate for that difference. Array indices in computer science almost always begin at zero rather than one; thus, it can be helpful to think of them as an offset from the start of the array rather than the nth array slot.